# Weblogic.xml and its inability to resolve a "URL mapping class" property

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have an ICEfaces 1.8.2 application that is targeted for WebLogic 10.3.2. That is, it is a faceted project using the "Oracle WebLogic Web App Extensions 10.3.2" facet (among others, such as ICEfaces EE 1.8.2, Java 1.6, Java Annotation Processing Support 5.0, Javascript 1.0, JSF 1.2, and Dynamic Web Module 2.5).

It fails to deploy and, as of now, I do not know why.

I may be grasping for straws, but I keep looking back at weblogic.xml because it shows an error on the URL mapping class. It says it cannot resolve weblogic.servlet.utils.ServletMapping, even though that is, in fact, the default.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I've searched quite a bit for an answer, but I've found documentation to be paltry and instances of this exact issue occurring nonexistent.

I am using Spring 2.5.6 (and the JAR is on the build path) - should I reference a mapping class of its? Do I need to explicitly reference a WebLogic JAR file?

Sorry for being all over the place. I just have no idea what to do. If this proves fruitless I will either post the stack trace of the failed deploy here or in a new thread. It just seems like I should be able to clear this error and at least eliminate the possibility of it being the culprit.

Thanks! 
Greg

Comment: Maybe the stack trace will help others, why not posting it here?

Comment: It's not a stack trace, it's what the eclipse weblogic.xml editor shows you in design mode when you create a new weblogic.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is automatically solved in new version of weblogic 12 c.

Or try this......

Add weblogic.jar to project build path.

Comment: I have weblogic 12c, and I am still getting the issue.  How is it automatically solved?

Comment: Where is weblogic.jar?  C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar\?  It's empty, how can that possibly help?  Where's the pom for it anyway?